# ThemeClassification Datasets - Clean Versions

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am looking for some small datasets to do theme classification on text for example like reuters, 20ng with benchmarking and also their clean versions. I found one very useful site - [Dataset](http://ana.cachopo.org/datasets-for-single-label-text-categorization). I want some more datasets in similar fashion. Where can I find them? I searched but I always end up with raw data which poses me a challenge to extract.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would be better suited on Open Data